# How do you add a manifest to an MFC application and set the supportedOS?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++, mfc, manifest

I'm trying to run the Microsoft Platform Ready Test Tool 4.6 for Windows Server 2012: http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=41676

I'm running into an issue. Its complaining that an MFC application I have has a manifest, but that manifest is missing the supportedOS section. I know how to add this in to C# projects, but how do you do it in MFC applications?

The MFC application shows up under, "Executables with manifest missing the supportedOS section".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just got it. Process was as follows:

Right click your solution, go to Properties. Drill down from Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Manifest File. Set the following:

Generate Manifest to "Yes (/MANIFEST)"

Manifest File to "app.manifest"

Now the trick...add a new file in your MFC application. Call it "app.manifest" as we made this the referenced name above. Make sure it has manifest XAML in it, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <!-- UAC Manifest Options
            If you want to change the Windows User Account Control level replace the 
            requestedExecutionLevel node with one of the following.

        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />

            Specifying requestedExecutionLevel node will disable file and registry virtualization.
            If you want to utilize File and Registry Virtualization for backward 
            compatibility then delete the requestedExecutionLevel node.
        -->
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>

  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
      <!-- A list of all Windows versions that this application is designed to work with. 
      Windows will automatically select the most compatible environment.-->

      <!-- If your application is designed to work with Windows Vista, uncomment the following supportedOS node-->
      <!--<supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/>-->

      <!-- If your application is designed to work with Windows 7, uncomment the following supportedOS node-->
      <!--<supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>-->

      <!-- If your application is designed to work with Windows 8, uncomment the following supportedOS node-->
      <!--<supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"/>-->

      <!-- If your application is designed to work with Windows 8.1, uncomment the following supportedOS node-->
      <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"/>

    </application>
  </compatibility>

  <!-- Enable themes for Windows common controls and dialogs (Windows XP and later) -->
  <!-- <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity
          type="win32"
          name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
          version="6.0.0.0"
          processorArchitecture="*"
          publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
          language="*"
        />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>-->

</asmv1:assembly>
```

Give yourself a tap on the back, you hero.

Tip: To view the manifest of your executable, open your executable in Notepad++ and scroll to the bottom. Its at the bottom. At least, this worked for me.

Comment: Please refer this also https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/cpp-docs/blob/main/docs/build/manifest-generation-in-visual-studio.md